# Add (Combine) CSS class attributes - icons or images

Tags: css

I am trying to show the proper amount (and color) of dots based on the class that is indicated for each various element.  There will be several different required colors (probably 7 or 8), and some will be mixed.  Chaining is not really an option, unfortunately, due to the large quantity of possible combinations.

```
<a class="reddot bluedot greendot purpledot"> Blah Blah Blah</a>
<a class="purpledot"> Blah Blah Blah</a>
<a class="greendot blackdot"> Blah Blah Blah</a>
```

I've tried the following css:

```
.reddot{
    background-image: url('/images/reddot.png');
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.bluedot{
    background-image: url('/images/bluedot.png');
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.reddot.bluedot{
    background-image: url('/images/reddot.png'),url('/images/bluedot.png');
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
etc.
```

Yes, I know the images overlap here ... that's not really the end of the world.  I think I know how to position them better.

The above css code gets me what I want, but there are so many combinations of the various elements that change.

I know I'm working with background-image here, and I know that the classes cannot be accumulated (therefore, chaining seems like the only way).  However, is there another way using CSS that I can find a way to add dots .. or other background or foreground images or icons .. simply by adding classes to the html?

I can't add  or any other hierarchy of classes.

Comment: Could you just insert some `span`s or small images into the link?

Comment: Are the colors always in the same slot? Eg "red" is always #2. Can you maintain space for all ~8 dots even if some of them are transparent?

Comment: @BryceHowitson, I might be able to accommodate that.  How would I make some of them transparent and some of them show?

Comment: CSS Variables with a set default are your friend here. See my answer below. Basically you use the added class to set a variable value for either color or background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you always want dots and that the colors are always in the same order...

### Gradients

You can do this with CSS `background-gradients` and `variables` but its a bit complex.

Here's an example (and on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/zYOmRpe) if you want to play with it) I made the default gray but you could change it to transparent if you don't want to visually show the slots.

```css
.dots {
 border: 1px #dadada solid;
 min-height: 2rem;
 width: 10rem;
 margin: 1rem 2rem;
 
 background:
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 1rem 50%, var(--c1, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 2.5rem 50%, var(--c2, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 4rem 50%, var(--c3, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
 radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 5.5rem 50%, var(--c4, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%);
}

.red {
 --c1:#D50000;
}
.gold {
 --c2:#FDD835;
}
.blue {
 --c3:#1976D2;
}
.green {
 --c4:#00E676;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots red blue"></div>
<div class="dots green"></div>
<div class="dots gold blue"></div>
<div class="dots red gold green blue"></div>
```

### *Edit: Using a background image instead*

If you don't like the look of a radial gradient, you could chain and position `background-image` the same way. In this case, you would use a variable for the file path you want to display in the background.

```css
.stackedBG {
 border: 1px #dadada solid;
 height: 40px;
 width: 160px; /* 40 *4 */
 margin: 1rem 2rem;

 background-color: transparent;
 background-image: var(--b1, none), var(--b2, none), var(--b3, none), var(--b4, none);
 /* all images are 40x40px */
 background-position: 0 0px, 40px 0, 80px 0, 120px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg1 {
 --b1:url(https://i.imgur.com/ivPLv2g.png);
}
.bg2 {
 --b2:url(https://i.imgur.com/v8GNPuX.png);
}
.bg3 {
 --b3:url(https://i.imgur.com/ywuzlHn.png);
}
.bg4 {
 --b4:url(https://i.imgur.com/peTsfUi.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="stackedBG bg3"></div>
<div class="stackedBG bg1"></div>
<div class="stackedBG bg2 bg4"></div>
<div class="stackedBG bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4"></div>
```

### *Edit 2: Positioning background*

I think the easiest way to position either of these options (if relative to the upper left isn't desired) is to use a pseudo-element. Contain the backgrounds in a `:after` or `:before` and then absolutely position the pseudo-element.

```css
.dots {
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
  min-height: 5rem;
  margin: 1rem 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  
  /* the important part */
  position: relative;
}

.dots:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  
  /* size is based on the background layout */
  width:6.5rem;
  height: 1rem;
  
  /* typically I would do positioning here
     But it's easier to show an example if its separate */
  
  background:
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 1rem 50%, var(--c1, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 2.5rem 50%, var(--c2, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
    radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 4rem 50%, var(--c3, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%),
 radial-gradient(1rem 1rem at 5.5rem 50%, var(--c4, #dadada) 45%, transparent 51%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* positioning */

.tr:after {
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.br:after {
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.tl:after {
  top: 0.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
}

.bl:after {
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
}


/* variables still work the same with the pseudo class */
.red {
 --c1:#D50000;
}
.gold {
 --c2:#FDD835;
}
.blue {
 --c3:#1976D2;
}
.green {
 --c4:#00E676;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">Parent Element</div>
<div class="dots red blue tr">Parent Element</div>
<div class="dots green tl">Parent Element</div>
<div class="dots gold blue br">Parent Element</div>
<div class="dots red gold green blue bl">Parent Element</div>
```

Comment: This is the gangster solution.

Comment: I'm really liking this one!  Question .. How can I pull those dots to the right side of the element?  I've tried adjusting the width, adding background-position: right bottom;.... I'm not able to pull them to the right.  I don't just want to position them to the right because they wont be as responsive.

Comment: I would put the dots into a `:after` pseudo-element and then position that inside your regular element. That way you always know what size it is and you can use the pseudo-element's origin to position the dots.

Comment: <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end reddot bluedot dots fc-draggable" style="top: 2023px; bottom: -2067px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;"><div class="fc-content"><div class="fc-time" data-start="4:40" data-full="4:40 PM - 4:50 PM"><span>4:40 - 4:50</span></div><div class="fc-title">Blah Blah Blah</div></div></a> ... Then the .dots css, Then the .colors css.  I tried ".dots:after" I tried ".fc-time-grid-event.dots:after" I tried ".fc-content.dots:after" .. For each of those :after statements, the dots did not show up.

Comment: It's pretty hard to see what's going on when that's all in a comment. I'll modify my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: This is amazing! Now .. to take it a step further, how would I put a 'colored Letter' in there instead of a colored circle? I made red.png, blue.png, etc.  The red is a Red R, the blue is a blue B, etc.  I made it so that when the class is not selected, it shows up as transparent.  I tried putting --- background-image: url('/images/red.png');
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; --- in the--c1 variable spot, but that's not working correctly.  I also tried changing 'radial-gradient' to some url:'...' , but That didnt work either

Comment: I added a background image example. Note all images should be the same physical dimensions to make calculations easier.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley I don't believe you can accomplish this with pure css.

My suggestion would be to append whatever dots you need to your `<a></a>` element. Like `<span class=""reddot></span>`. Then you can then style then independently, and let them position themselves naturally.

I've made an example here: [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxp13ay6/)